# How to solve $ \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=e^x $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE:
$$
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=e^x
$$

I can't think of any immediate available tool to help me with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Solve the homogeneous equation (put 0 on the right). Then look for particular solutions - you can look up that in your text book.

Comment: Doesn't that method require the derivative to be with respect to the variable inside the exponential? Notice that this problem is different than $y''(x)=e^x$

Comment: @paul this is a nonlinear equation. As it is $$\ddot{x} = f(x)$$ - you can integrate to give a first order ode. Then you can try to progress but you end up with a square root of the function of X then which you can solve for specific conditions.

Comment: @paul no - because you have $x(t)$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Reading too quick sorry. Saying x is x(t) would have helped us hasty readers...

Comment: With CAS: $x(t)=\ln \left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 \left(\tanh ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{c_1
   (c_2+t){}^2}\right)-1\right)\right)$

Comment: Have you seen similar problems? Something of the form $x''(t) = g(x(t))$?

Comment: @HansEngler Admittedly, I have not. It would be very nice to see a systematic way of solving such equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $p=\frac{dx}{dt}$ therefore $\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{dp}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=p\frac{dp}{dx}$ therefore we have

$$p\frac{dp}{dx}=e^x\Rightarrow pdp=e^xdx\Rightarrow \frac{p^2}{2}=e^x+c'_1\Rightarrow p=\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}$$

Now we have

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}}=dt \\ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c_1}}\left(\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}-\sqrt{c_1}}{\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}+\sqrt{c_1}}\right)\right) = t+c_2$$

because ($2e^x+c_1=s^2\Rightarrow 2e^xdx=2sds$)

$$
\begin{align}
I=&\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2e^x+c_1}} \\
=&\int \frac{sds}{\frac{s^2-c_1}{2}}\frac{1}{s} \\
=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c_1}}\int \left(\frac{1}{s-\sqrt{c_1}}-\frac{1}{s+\sqrt{c_1}} \right)ds \\
I=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c_1}}\left(\ln \left(\frac{s-\sqrt{c_1}}{s+\sqrt{c_1}}\right)\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $\frac{dx}{dt}$. As a result, both the left and the right hand side are now derivatives: 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2}
\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2
=\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = e^x \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} e^x 
$$
Integrate both sides to obtain the first order equation
$$
\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2
= 2 e^x +C_1 \, . 
$$ 
Taking square roots, you arrive at two separable first order equations:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \pm \sqrt{ 2 e^x +C_1} \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ 2 e^x +C_1}} = \pm dt
$$ 
Integrate and solve for $x(t)$.